# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add_cookies')

Tags: javascript, playwright

I am getting this error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add_cookies')

But I am unsure how I can declare it further? What amI doing wrong in the code?

Added the snippet below:

```
import { test, expect, browser_context, add_cookies} from '@playwright/test';

test('test', async ({ page, }) => {

  await page.goto('https://myurl.com/');
  
  await page.waitForTimeout(4000)

  browser_context.add_cookies(["cookiename", "myvalue"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass through a browser object that give you a context to be sure to be able to add cookie

```
test('test', async ({ page, browser })) => {

   await page.goto('https://myurl.com/');
  
   await page.waitForTimeout(4000)
  
   const browserContext = await browser.newContext();
   browserContext.add_cookies(["cookiename", "myvalue"];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I tried that but it gives me this error: 

"Cannot find name browser" do you know why this is?

Comment: you have to define a browser object by creating a new one `browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false });`or pass the browser object as parameter of your test

I edit my reply to add second point